# My .NET web service method needs to return a JSON result to the calling client (an iOS device), but is returning a bunch of \r\n's

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net, http-get

Presently, I'm returning a `string` out of my web method call, which the iOS device gets.  When the iOS gets this data, the string representation of the JSON object, it contains a bunch of `\n\r` characters as well as a number of backslashes (`\`) - so as a result, the iOS device doesn't recognize this as valid JSON.  see below:

> "{\r\n  \"byteData\": \"UEsDBAoAAAAAALlp...etc."

I am not sure if it's because of any flawed code below- is there anything you see I'm doing wrong below?  I am using JSON.NET.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetTpkMap(string fileName)
        {
            // go out to file share to get map
            string sharePath = string.Format(@"\\server\shared\TPK\{0}", fileName + ".tpk");
            FileStream fs = File.Open(sharePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            // load FileStream into a byte array
            int length = (int)fs.Length;
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            fs.Read(data, 0, length);

            fs.Close();

            // convert byteData to a Base64String to pass back to the client
            string strData = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

            dynamic tpkByteData = new JObject();
            tpkByteData.byteData = strData;

            JObject val = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(tpkByteData);

            return val.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you inspecting this string? \r\n is return/linefeed, and \" is often the way tools show `"` to indicate that it's not the end of the string.

Comment: Well, the iOS device doesn't recognize this as valid JSON because of the new line and carriage return characters.  This string was sent to me from the iOS device from the iOS developer.

Comment: I think you don't need to serialize your return result, just let MVC do it for you.  Have you tried `public ActionResult  GetTpkMap(string fileName)
{
 return Json(new{ byteData = strData});
}` ?

Comment: I have not, I will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the overload of [`ToString()`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString_1.htm) that takes the formatting parameter:

```
return val.ToString(Formatting.None, yourJsonFormatters);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JSON converters (formatters as you indicate)... I'll have to read up on them